# ［Dell PowerEdge R640] BIOS Settings

Tags: dell-poweredge

I am managing my lab system via R640. Found it has an item in System BIOS called User Accessible USB Ports and I set to All Ports Off (Dynamic) and found one of front USB port cannot work anymore. How could I enable it back dynamically?

Thank you.

NOTE: From the manual,  “All Ports Off (Dynamic) disables all front and back USB ports during POST and front ports can be enabled or disabled dynamically by an authorized user or authorized users without resetting the system.”

Comment: What do you mean enable it "dynamically"?

Comment: Because this item is All Ports Off(Dynamic) so I think it should able to enable some USB ports back from current disabled state to enabled state.  That’s what I think but idk how.

Answer (score 0):

Dell has nice Manuals, hows about to read them? 
https://www.dell.com/support/home/de/de/debsdt1/product-support/product/poweredge-r640/manuals

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read the manual but have no clue by how. :(